# Having several keys refer to the same bibliography entry

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, alias

Is it possible to have several keys referring to the same bibliography entry (using `biblatex`+Biber)?

For example, I'd like `\cite{Tolkien:1954:LordOfTheRings}` and `\cite{lotr}` to have exactly the same effect when used in a document (and produce only a single bibliography entry, when both are used in the same document).

Comment: Assuming that `lotr` is defined in your bibliography and you want to use `Tolkien:1954:LordOfTheRings`, try `\makeatletter \expandafter\def\csname b@Tolkien:1954:LordOfTheRings\endcsname{\b@lotr} \makeatother` in your document preamble?

Comment: @Werner: But wouldn't one have to use `\cite{\csname b@Tolkien:1954:LordOfTheRings\endcsname}` in the main text?

Comment: @lockstep: AFAIK, `\cite{<stuff>}` checks for the existence of `\b@<stuff>` via a construction. So you should just be able to use `\cite{Tolkien:1954:LordOfTheRings}`.

Comment: @Werner: I'd love to see a MWE using this trick. :-)

Comment: @lockstep: This trick, with some hiccups, worked with regular `bibtex`; not `biblatex`. `biblatex` defines things in a much more complicated way it seems.

Comment: Have you tried doing it with `@crossref` directly in the .bib-File?  I uses this occasionally for fixing typos or convention issues in keys to stay backward compatible. I have not yet tried to use both keys within the same document, so it might be perfectly possible that you end up with two entries.

Comment: @Daniel: The `@crossref` type doesn't exist; using the `crossref` field gives duplicate entries in the bibliography list if both keys are used in the same document.

Comment: @Caramdir: You are right of course, that is how I actually used it.

Comment: I'm looking into this for biber 0.9.8. Probably something like this @BOOK{key1, IDS={key2,key3, ... keyn}, ...} where you can cite by either the main key or any of the secondary IDs. I need a little bit of biblatex support to deal with citations of the same entry via different keys as this can't be dealt with entirely in biber.

Comment: @PLK That would be the perfect solution. If you do implement this, please keep up us updated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

With newer versions of biblatex (≥2.0) and biber (≥0.9.8) you can define your entries as normal and use the  "IDS" field for extra citations keys:

```
@BOOK{key,
  IDS = {key2, key3, ..., keyn},
  .
  .
}
```

You can then cite by any of the keys, you can cite by any of them mixed in the same section and and you can use `\nocite{*}` too - it won't duplicate entries in the bibliography. In fact, the other keys are just aliases to the main key which owns the entry in the `.bbl` and are redirected to the main key before any label generation etc. happens.

It will also detect if you use a key as a primary key and also an alias elsewhere, in which case it will disable the alias. It also notices duplicate aliases as well as keys now.

Comment: Great news -- the `biblatex`/`biber` combo keeps getting better and better!

Comment: We have some pretty significant features coming. I wonder if it would be possible to have somewhere on here to announce and request comments and suggestions for them - Community wiki perhaps? The problem is that the new features are not so visible and so problems are often reported a long time after they were introduced when someone discovers the features in the biblatex Release file.

Comment: Is there some update about official support for this from the biblatex side?

Comment: Good question. I have an unofficial biblatex 1.7 patch for this but the biblatex maintainer seems to have disappeared temporarily for about six months and I don't know how to contact him.

Comment: Seems still to be an issue: I get `Undefined control sequence \keyalias`. So are any update on this by now? Still biblatex person not available? 
@PLK: can you say what *slightly hacked* means? I mean is there a patch to see the actual difference? The link to the biblatex.sty seems outdated.

Comment: This is fully supported now and has been for a while. it looks to me like you perhaps have an outdated version of biblatex? Or, you are not using biber as the backend, which this requires.

Comment: I have the same issue using a contemporary Ubuntu which seems to ship 1.7-1. Do you know what version is compatible?

Comment: 1.7 biber or biblatex? I think this was done a couple of years ago in biber 0.9.8

Comment: Ubuntu ships biblatex-1.7-1, as per http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=biblatex

Comment: That's really old, however, I assume that if this is a TL installation, users can just run the TL updater to get the latest version.

Comment: Is this still valid today? Has it been integrated into the non-hacked version?

Comment: Just to be clear, this has been fully integrated into biber/biblatex for a couple of years now.

Comment: If I see it correctly, then the entries have to define their own alias keys rather than having another entry with the target key referencing the already existing entry.
My scenario is that I have a bib file exported through Zotero. And I cannot manually patch that file each time I export. So having a second file defining the aliases would be great.

Comment: What you want here isn't possible and is such a niche requirement, I doubt it would be implemented. However, I imagine that you could do something with cloning sourcemaps and `crossref/xdata`.

Answer (score 14):

The following, taken from ["Alias for BiBTeX Keys" on comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/6FbPs7f58pE/TyOlZfjgt10J), provides `\bibalias{<alias>}{<source>}` and should use `\acite{<citation>}` instead of `\cite{<citation>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}% http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex
\bibliography{references}

\makeatletter
% \bibalias{<alias>}{<source>} makes \cite{<alias>} equivalent to \cite{<source>}
\newcommand\bibalias[2]{%
  \@namedef{bibali@#1}{#2}%
}

\newtoks\biba@toks
\newcommand\acite[2][]{%
  \biba@toks{\cite#1}%
  \def\biba@comma{}%
  \def\biba@all{}%
  \@for\biba@one:=#2\do{%
    \@ifundefined{bibali@\biba@one}{%
      \edef\biba@all{\biba@all\biba@comma\biba@one}%
    }{%
      \PackageInfo{bibalias}{%
        Replacing citation `\biba@one' with `\@nameuse{bibali@\biba@one}'
      }%
      \edef\biba@all{\biba@all\biba@comma\@nameuse{bibali@\biba@one}}%
    }%
    \def\biba@comma{,}%
  }%
  \edef\biba@tmp{\the\biba@toks{\biba@all}}%
  \biba@tmp
}
\makeatother

\bibalias{Tolkien:1954:LordOfTheRings}{lotr}

\begin{document}
The reference~\acite{Tolkien:1954:LordOfTheRings} is
exactly the same as~\acite{lotr}.

\bibstyle{plain}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where `references.bib` resembles:

```
@book{lotr,
  author  = "J.R.R. Tolkien",
  title   = "{The Lord of the Rings}",
  address = "New York",
  year    = 1954,
  publisher = "Ballantine Books"
}
```

Comment: I've packed it up at http://absatzen.de/, but I don't remember why it's v0.2 anymore. (Also, it's quite possible that it will not work with more advanced syntactic forms of `\cite`. I think it'll accept anything that has a comma-separated list of labels as the first mandatory argument and pretty arbitrary stuff between the command and that argument.)

Comment: This seems to work well. I would have preferred something that is completely transparent in the actual document (i.e. everything is defined in the `.bib` file), but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: I'll accept this until biber/biblatex directly supports multiple keys.

Answer (score 1):

Pure-`bibtex` answer:

Put this in the preamble and then use `\bibalias{new key}{old, long, and cumbersome key}`. It is the original LaTeX `\cite` macro, modified only by the two unindented "magic" lines.

```
% Bib aliases
\makeatletter
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
\edef\magic##1{\let##1\expandafter\noexpand\csname bibalias@\@citeb\endcsname}%
\magic\tmp \ifx\tmp\relax\else \let\@citeb\tmp\fi
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
\def\bibalias#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname bibalias@#1\endcsname{#2}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Does this work together with `biblatex`?

Comment: It probably does (although tbh I don't know what a `biblatex` is). It works by tweaking the lowest level of LaTeX's `\cite`, so probably works with anything that does not touch that command; else, adapting it should be fairly trivial!

Comment: I had the feeling that it probably wouldn't work with `biblatex` since that uses a new way to implement the `\cite` macros and indeed, it didn't work for me just now. (To be fair, I cannot say for sure that I dibn't do something wrong, I just copied the code, wrote a `\bibalias` and expected it to work with `\cite`.) Maybe you want to warn people that your solution will not work with `biblatex` out of the box (the question is specifically about `biblatex`). I assume the "trivial" modifications will lead to something like in [Werner's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37264/35864)?