# How can I have two bibtex tags for a single entry?

Tags: bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Having several keys refer to the same bibliography entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37233/having-several-keys-refer-to-the-same-bibliography-entry)

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{4155349, 
author={Pollitt, Mark M.}, 
booktitle={Systematic Approaches to Digital Forensic Engineering, 2007. SADFE 2007. Second International Workshop on}, title={An Ad Hoc Review of Digital Forensic Models}, 
year={2007}, 
month={april}, 
volume={}, 
number={}, 
pages={43 -54}, 
keywords={digital forensic models;forensic science;computer crime;}, 
doi={10.1109/SADFE.2007.3}, 
ISSN={},}
```

My problem is that I'm already using this reference in many documents. I gave it the name `pollitt:models`.  I'd rather use `4155349` since that's the official name, but I don't want to break my old files. Is there any way to have a link or two names?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37233/having-several-keys-refer-to-the-same-bibliography-entry