# bibtex with multiple aliases for the same reference

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

Is this something that I can do with `bibtex`?  I have a few different manuscripts with some other collaborators and it would be easier for me if I could make `\cite{foo}` and `\cite{bar}` point to the same thing.  Of course there are ways to work around this by changing `\cite{foo}` to `\cite{bar}` everywhere in the manuscripts, or by duplicating `bibtex` entries in the `.bib` file, but I would rather not do these things.

Comment: I have on my todo list to try out http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/egs/crosstex/, which should solve this kind of problem...

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/can-a-bibtex-entry-be-given-more-than-one-reference-name and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37233/having-several-keys-refer-to-the-same-bibliography-entry?lq=1

Answer (score 21):

I'm not aware of any possibility to remap keys in a `.bib` file; if this is true (and I think it is) then this is really a shortcoming.

So my solution is based on doing the remapping in the LaTeX preamble, and as often these days I use  the `prop` datatype of LaTeX3 as that is really useful in such circumstances.

The basic idea is to use a property list that stores the citation keys as keys and the target keys as values. Then whenever a citation command is run we look up the key and if there is a mapping we use the mapping instead. This way the `.aux` file will end up having only the remapped keys in it and BibTeX will only find those.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_cite_map_prop
\tl_new:N \l_citekey_result_tl

\cs_new:Npn \mapcitekey #1#2 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
       {  \prop_gput:Nnn  \g_cite_map_prop  {##1} {#1}   }
}

\cs_new:Npn \getcitekey #1 {
   \prop_get:NoN \g_cite_map_prop{#1}  \l_citekey_result_tl
   \quark_if_no_value:NF \l_citekey_result_tl
       {  \tl_set_eq:NN #1  \l_citekey_result_tl  }
}

\cs_new:Npn \showcitekeymaps {\prop_show:N  \g_cite_map_prop }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This gives us `\mapcitekey` with two arguments: the first is our major key that we want to use with BibTeX and the second is the alternate key that we want to remap. In fact the second argument can also be a comma separated list, e.g.,

```
\mapcitekey{hello}{world}
\mapcitekey{foo}{bar,baz,foobar}

\showcitekeymaps
```

This will give us

```
The property list \g_cite_map_prop contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {world}  =>  {hello}
>  {bar}  =>  {foo}
>  {baz}  =>  {foo}
>  {foobar}  =>  {foo}.
```

Now to look things up we have `\getcitekey` and what remains to be done is to patch the citation commands to make use of this key. I have done this below for `\cite` and `\nocite` from standard LaTeX. If some other citation package such as `natbib` is used one needs to patch its citation commands. Basically you need to look for the places where the command `\citation` is being written to the `.aux` file and the command that is used in the argument to `\citation` is the one that holds the key needs to be changed.

So here are the patches necessary:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@citex}{\if@filesw}{\getcitekey\@citeb \if@filesw}%
    {\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}
\patchcmd{\nocite}{\if@filesw}{\getcitekey\@citeb \if@filesw}%
    {\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}
\makeatletter
```

With those definitions and the remapping above, the input

```
\cite{foo} \cite{bar} \cite{world} \cite{baz}
```

will give us the following citations in the aux file:

```
\citation{foo}
\citation{foo}
\citation{hello}
\citation{foo}
```

---

By the way, duplicating BibTeX entries with different keys is *not* going to work (as suggested in the question). That would result in getting the same reference twice.

Answer (score 7):

You could switch to `biblatex`. There exists an entry field `IDS` which does exactly what you want.

```
@Article{hier,
  IDS = {da},
  author    = {Vorname Nachname AND Maximilian Mustermann},
  title     = {Dies ist ein testtitel},
  journal   = {Testjournal},
  year      = {2001},
  timestamp = {2018-01-08},
}
```

Now you can cite this entry as `\cite{hier}` as well as as `\cite{da}`.

(no idea if the as as part is proper English, but it sounds sound.)

Comment: It seems I can get this to work only with biber, not with bibtex as a backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, it might work for you.

```
\newcommand\OurCite[2]{\cite{#1}}% In the source for author 1
```

or

```
\newcommand\OurCite[2]{\cite{#2}}% In the source for author 2
```

and in the document :

```
(...) see e.g.{} \OurCite{foo}{bar}
```

Comment: the OP is looking for a a way to remap from the outside and not to change all the different manuscripts he received (and perhaps get in a different version later again). If he does what you suggest then he would be easier of just to replace the cite keys directly.