# Renaming BibTeX keys without breaking existing documents

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I have a big BibTeX file with entries with keys such as `smith-jones-2011` and `shah-2018`. I'd like to rename these keys into `Smith2011` and `Shah2018` instead but I don't want to break the LaTeX files that refer to the old keys. Is there a good automated way to change all of the keys in the BibTeX file and updating the LaTeX files?

Comment: Start a new database for new documents.

Comment: As the .bib and tex files are both plain text, just  use a tool for search & replace in several files. There are many. If you are a Linux user, for example, a good option could be  [rpl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251742/34224).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5256, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417917

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.bib` files have no knowledge about the `.tex` documents they are used in, so a `.bib` file can't magically go back through all your files and change the citation keys.

A simple search-and-replace job across all your `.tex` might be enough for you. If your database is big you may want to try and automate this by obtaining a list of old and new keys that can be worked through one-by-one.

---

If you are using `biblatex` (with Biber) you could use the `ids` field to keep the old name alive. See [kregkob](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/103553/kregkob)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5256/35864) to [bibtex with multiple aliases for the same reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44877/35864) and also [PLK](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1657/plk)'s answer to [Having several keys refer to the same bibliography entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37233/35864)

```
@article{Smith2011,
  ids       = {smith-jones-2011},% <- old key
  author    = {Jane Smith and Emma Jones},
  title     = {Title},
  journal   = {Journal of Stuff},
  year      = {2011},
  volume    = {12},
}
```

---

A bit of a hack would be to `crossref` the old name to the new one

```
@article{Smith2011,
  author    = {Jane Smith and Emma Jones},
  title     = {Title},
  journal   = {Journal of Stuff},
  year      = {2011},
  volume    = {12},
}

@article{smith-jones-2011,
  crossref = {Smith2011}
}
```

as suggested by [frabjous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/411/frabjous) in [Can a bibtex entry be given more than one reference name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5248/35864). This need not work with all `.bst` files and can lead to duplication in the bibliography and other weird side-effects if both names are used in the same document.

---

If you are exclusively using `biblatex` (with Biber) you should be fine with `ids`. Otherwise I would suggest the search and replace solution.